# Feeding UIView with data

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiview

Suppose you have a `UIView` that displays data from some model object. When the model changes in the background, it notifies its listeners via some subscription mechanism; a pretty common pattern...

What I've been doing on iOS is subscribing to the model notifications in a `ViewControllers` `viewWillAppear`; refreshing the appropriate views in response to the change notification; and ceasing my subscription in `viewWillDisappear`. This way, it was ensured that I wouldn't waste resources by tracking the changes when the given view controller was off-screen, so I was happy with this solution.

However, my current project needs some views, that track a model object, and they are used all over the place in several view controllers. If I would use the previous approach, then the subscription/unsubscription plumbing would have to be duplicated in many view controllers. I was wondering, whether this logic could be put in the view itself? Although the `UIView's` lifecycle events (willMoveToSuperview: and willMoveToWindow:) have somewhat vague semantics in this regard, this has to be possible, since that's what Apple is doing with the iAd display views – i.e. ADBannerView doesn't require any plumbing to start displaying ads aside from putting it in your view hierarchy, and it's pullin data from remote sources, so it must not be wasting resources by having unnecessary subscriptions to the iAd servers. 
Has anyone done this thing? I.e. reliably coupling expensive change-tracking mechanisms with the `UIView` lifecycle events?

Answer (score 0):

I use this procedure quite frequently though using `viewDidAppear` since I can not be sure some other view controller will not be calling `viewWillAppear` before the current one's `viewWillDisappear` will be called and this can be inconvenience when you are assigning a delegate to some "shared instance".

Anyway I always use the view controllers to handle this reloads and then call specific views to be refreshed. There were a few specific cases where I unsubscribed in the `removeFromSuperView` method but you can understand this is not the best approach since the view could be then again added to some view as a subview and the subscription is not done automatically. But then again I do use this in cases where the view itself is self retained due to the subscription for which the most common situation is using a timer or a display link (this can again be avoided by using 2 classes but that's another thing).

If this subscription/unsubscription is used on the level of view controllers as in checking if the view indeed is visible I rather suggest you keep it there and manually subscribe/unsubscribe views owned by the view controller. If for no other reason your code will be more manageable.

If on the other hand this needs to be on the level of some specific view type (creating a library or even simply reusing) then I would try to handle this in some `init` and the `dealloc` method. Again if resources are tight I would move the logic to the view controller.

In any case if you find a solid solution putting this logic strictly to the view I would be glad to hear about it.

**Edit on the comment to add the self retained solution:**

When it comes to the issue when a class is retained by the subscription such as a timer or a notification center what you do is create 2 classes. One represents your interface and has all the methods you need to get specific data and if needed contains a delegate to which the caller can subscribe (having a weak link), let's call it class A. Now this class contains another class which contains the actual subscriptions to outside sources such as notification center and is self retained, class B. So class A is not self retained as it has no direct subscriptions to the notification center, timers... That means class A will be deallocated properly while class B will persist and cause a potential memory leak. Class B then does need an explicit call to be unsubscribed so it is released and this should be done in the class A `dealloc` method.

I guess simple explanation can be a bit complicated so do look at this code:

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@class ClassA;
@class ClassB;

@protocol ClassBDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)classBPing:(ClassB *)sender;
@end

@interface ClassB : NSObject
@property NSTimer *timer;
@property (weak) id<ClassBDelegate> delegate;
- (void)beginNotificationHandling;
- (void)endNotificationHandling;
@end

@implementation ClassB
- (void)beginNotificationHandling {
    if(self.timer == nil) {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}
- (void)endNotificationHandling {
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}
- (void)onTimer {
    [self.delegate classBPing:self];
}

@end

@interface ClassA()<ClassBDelegate>
@property ClassB *classBInstance;
@end
@implementation ClassA

- (instancetype)init {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.classBInstance = [[ClassB alloc] init];
        self.classBInstance.delegate = self;
        [self.classBInstance beginNotificationHandling];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // once this class is deallocated the classB instance must be invalidated so it is deallocated as well
    [self.classBInstance endNotificationHandling];
}

- (void)classBPing:(ClassB *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Ping");
}

@end
```

Note this is only the source file, there is no need to have the `classB` in the header file as you should not use it outside the `classA` at all. Now using this procedure you can add any methods, delegates or whatever from the `classA` to handle events.

Comment: Init and dealloc becomes problematic when the subscription retains the subscriber (e.g. NSNotificationCenter does this)

Comment: Yes as I mentioned the issue comes in when you have a self retained situation as you just mentioned one. Let me edit the answer to add this already mentioned "another thing".